# What happens if all my identification documents expire abroad?

Tags: eu, identification

If I only have Polish passport and Polish ID and live in UK but both my Polish documents expire.

What can I do to renew my any Polish document if I need to travel again? 
I do not have any British identification at all.

Comment: I would start by going to the polish embassy and/or their website

Comment: I agree with @ppumkin, how that is dealt with depends on the country which has issued the documents, the best thing to do would be go through the embassy.

Answer (score 4):

As a national of any country you can go to your nearest consulate or embassy and get your expired passport renewed, for a fixed fee, without providing any other valid identification.

You do not need any other valid identification, as the expired passport already contains your identification numbers and will be reverified when a new one is created. You can pay extra to expedited the process or apply for an emergency passport which may be issued the same day or within 48 hours.

If you have lost all your ID's and passports, you must go to the nearest embassy, where the process is completely different and slightly unpleasant.

--EDIT

(Possibly only applies within EU States)
I have also recently learnt that you can fly back to your countries Capital City with expired documentation by using the countries official airline.

For Example:

1. I am in the UK and all I have is a expired Polish ID.
2. I can go to closest airport, go to Lot (Polish Airlines) Declare document is out of date to notify border patrol on other side
3. Purchase a flight to Warsaw (Capital)
4. Get processed on the border in Poland.

This is good in case you need to get out QUICK for some reason. But it has a premium price of the flight which is usually more expensive. But can be sorted on the same day.

Comment: The added option of going to your capital city may only be true for Poland.

Comment: @MarkJohnson possibly so.  It certainly isn't true for the US: there is a temporary regulation in place because of COVID-19 that allows US citizens to fly to the US with an expired passport under certain conditions, but it will almost certainly be allowed to expire at some point.  Furthermore, it does not depend on the airline one flies with (the US has no "official airline") nor on the destination within the US.  Exceptions such as this are probably not uncommon, but I'd be surprised if one can formulate a general rule such as the one expressed here.  The details will be too variable.

Comment: I think this is true for all EU states.. but I am pretty sure the same applies world wide because its not the Airlines that do border checks.. sure they do record and register your ID

Comment: Nowadays you might have problems getting back to the UK. Most countries don't care when you leave, but they care when a foreigner arrives. Problem with airlines is they might not know the law well enough and refuse to let you on board (since they have to pay for your flight back if you are refused entry).

Answer (score 4):

UK and other authorities will need you to procure another ID for any official purposes, including traveling. If you still have recently expired documents, renewing them is much easier and it might even be possible to travel in some cases.

If you don't, your country's consular network should help you (same thing if you have only one ID and you lose it). Depending on how your country works, they can do that by asking personal details and checking with the relevant local authorities back home (e.g. look up your biometric details in a national file, find out if there is someone matching your details in the registry of births, getting others to vouch for you, etc.) Registering with your embassy beforehand, if your country offers it, might also simplify things down the line.